# How do I query the version of Xerces at runtime for an app deployed to JBoss 7.2?

Tags: java, jboss, xerces

Normally you can query the version of Xerces [as documented here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-general.html) using [org.apache.xerces.impl.Version.getVersion()](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/impl/Version.html#getVersion%28%29).  This does not work at runtime under JBoss due to a ClassNotFoundException:

Code:

```
Class.forName( "org.apache.xerces.impl.Version" )
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.impl.Version from [Module "deployment.tep-web-services.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:51)
```

What is the runtime location of the Version class under JBoss 7.2?

Answer (score 1):

I found my Xerces jar in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xerces/main`, but I'm not sure if that is 'standard' or not.  It did contain an `org.apache.xerces.impl.Version` class.  I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to load it with `Class.forName()` from JBoss...